# How to Install Composer.php

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

I'm in need of using composer.php in my website (https://getcomposer.org/) but i am struggling to install and don't know where to begin even from looking at the getting started docs.
I am using Mac OSX and code in php.

It says to install locally:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

or

```
$ php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

or globally:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Where about do I put these commands? I have tried to put them in a php file (syntax errors) and then try to run in terminal but get `command not found`.

Sorry but i am extremely new to this kind of coding/installing to have very limited knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the above commands are supposed to be executed on the command line (Shell or sometimes called Terminal). You have to have `curl` and `php` installed. You can also use `wget` or a browser to download the installer script. The installer script is a simple PHP CLI script.

Answer (score 0):

Since moest servers don't run on Mac Os X (and they shouldn't) it is best to have a 'development' machine you connect to.

If you don't have a spare server lying around (most of us don't) the best solution is to use a VirtualMachine that runs on your computer. E.g. Oracle Virtualbox

A nice tutorial can be found here: http://otaqui.com/blog/1652/setting-up-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-for-web-development-with-multiple-sites-using-mod_vhost_alias-and-virtualdocumentroot/

You then have all your app software (e.g. php, curl, ...) on your development virtual machine (personally i use debian, but ubuntu, windows server,.. all do the trick).

You fire up the mac os x terminal, ssh into your server and then execute the composer commands. This way, if you app crashes, only the virtual machine crashes and it doesn't affect your local machine.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I am just in the process of setting up the virtual machine. Can i ask another possibly stupid question - say if i setup the virtual machine with curl, php and composer installed, can i then work with them on my local machine or must i work in the virtual machine for all development that uses them?

Comment: you will have to work on your development machine. But you can mount the virtual machine (as in the blog) in your filesystem